# How to use STL sort to sort custom class object with template specialization?

Tags: c++, stl

I am learning C++ STL now. I know if I want to accomplish custom function while using STL algorithm or container, I can use functor or template specialization. For instance:

```
class my_class {
public:
    int id;
    int num;
};

// Definition of hash and comparison functor of my_class, which is so-called Explicit Template Specialization
namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<my_class> {
    size_t operator()(const my_class& e) const
    {
        return hash<int>()(e.id);
    }
};
template <>
struct equal_to<my_class> {
    bool operator()(const my_class& le, const my_class& re) const
    {
        return le.id == re.id;
    }
};
};

int main()
{
    unordered_set<my_class> s;
    s.insert(my_class{ 0, 10 });
    s.insert(my_class{ 1, 30 });
    s.insert(my_class{ 0, 20 });
    s.insert(my_class{ 2, 40 });
    for (auto e : s) {
        cout << "Value of ID " << e.id << ": " << e.num << endl;
    }
    cout << "Size of set: " << s.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But how can I use STL sort to sort custom class objects with template specialization?

The follow is wrong:

```
class my_class {
public:
    int id;
    int num;
};
namespace std {
template <>
struct comp<my_class> {
    bool operator()(const my_class& le, const my_class& re) const
    {
        return le.id < re.id;
    }
};
};

int main()
{
    vector<my_class> v;
    v.push_back(my_class{ 2, 10 });
    v.push_back(my_class{ 3, 10 });
    v.push_back(my_class{ 0, 10 });
    v.push_back(my_class{ 1, 10 });
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    cout << "Vector after sorting:" << endl;
    for (const auto& e : v) {
        cout << "Value of ID " << e.id << ": " << e.num << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: std::sort requires the object to have a < operator defined

Comment: @Tom Not if you pass a predicate, see the link posted above.

Comment: Are you actually sure you need a template specialization?

Comment: I think it's not possible if you use: `void
    sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last)`. In the source code for gcc 4.8.2 I can see an implementation for sort that does not use any compare function. So you can't overload it.

Comment: Thanks for everyone. The problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. This is the source code for sort (gcc 4.8.2):

```
/**
 *  @brief Sort the elements of a sequence.
 *  @ingroup sorting_algorithms
 *  @param  __first   An iterator.
 *  @param  __last    Another iterator.
 *  @return  Nothing.
 *
 *  Sorts the elements in the range @p [__first,__last) in ascending order,
 *  such that for each iterator @e i in the range @p [__first,__last-1),  
 *  *(i+1)<*i is false.
 *
 *  The relative ordering of equivalent elements is not preserved, use
 *  @p stable_sort() if this is needed.
*/
template<typename _RandomAccessIterator>
  inline void
  sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last)
  {
    typedef typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::value_type
_ValueType;

  // concept requirements
    __glibcxx_function_requires(_Mutable_RandomAccessIteratorConcept<
    _RandomAccessIterator>)
    __glibcxx_function_requires(_LessThanComparableConcept<_ValueType>)
    __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first, __last);

    if (__first != __last)
  {
    std::__introsort_loop(__first, __last,
            std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2);
    std::__final_insertion_sort(__first, __last);
  }
}

/**
 *  @brief Sort the elements of a sequence using a predicate for comparison.
 *  @ingroup sorting_algorithms
 *  @param  __first   An iterator.
 *  @param  __last    Another iterator.
 *  @param  __comp    A comparison functor.
 *  @return  Nothing.
 *
 *  Sorts the elements in the range @p [__first,__last) in ascending order,
 *  such that @p __comp(*(i+1),*i) is false for every iterator @e i in the
 *  range @p [__first,__last-1).
 *
 *  The relative ordering of equivalent elements is not preserved, use
 *  @p stable_sort() if this is needed.
*/
template<typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _Compare>
  inline void
  sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
 _Compare __comp)
  {
    typedef typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::value_type
_ValueType;

    // concept requirements
    __glibcxx_function_requires(_Mutable_RandomAccessIteratorConcept<
    _RandomAccessIterator>)
    __glibcxx_function_requires(_BinaryPredicateConcept<_Compare, _ValueType,
              _ValueType>)
    __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first, __last);

    if (__first != __last)
  {
    std::__introsort_loop(__first, __last,
            std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2, __comp);
    std::__final_insertion_sort(__first, __last, __comp);
  }
}
```

In the implementation for

```
void sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last)
```

there is no compare function so you can't customize it by template specialization. You have to use

```
void sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last, _Compare __comp)
```

Answer (score 1):

While the specialization of e.g. `std::less` is taken into account for comparing keys in a `std::map`, the default behavior for `std::sort` is to use `operator <` (overload #1 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)). It is still valid to specialize `std::less`, but you need to explicitly pass it to `std::sort` like this:

```
namespace std {
    template <>
    struct less<my_class> {
         bool operator()(const my_class& le, const my_class& re) const
         {
             return le.id < re.id;
         }
    };
}

// Fill vector with my_class instances...

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::less<my_class>{});
```

Note how this differs from inserting items in a map:

```
// std::less<my_class> is used by default to compare key instances:
std::map<my_class, int> m;

m[{1, 1}] = 42;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specialise `std::equal_to` or `std::less`, you can just provide `operator ==` and `operator <` such that they can be found from an unqualified call.

You specialise `std::hash`, because there is no `operator hash`.

```
bool operator ==(const my_class& le, const my_class& re) const
{
    return le.id == re.id;
}

bool operator <(const my_class& le, const my_class& re) const
{
    return le.id < re.id;
}
```

Having provided these, it is also useful to provide overloads for `!=`, `>` `<=` and `>=` in terms of those. You can do that explicitly, or inherit from something like [`boost::totally_ordered`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/utility/operators.htm)

```
class my_class : public boost::totally_ordered<my_class> {
public:
    int id;
    int num;
};
```

> I know if I want to accomplish custom function while using STL
>   algorithm or container, I can use functor or template specialization.

Not necessarily. The language provides customisation points in multiple ways. Some of them are by functors, some by template specialisation, and in this case, by [providing an overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LessThanComparable) for an operator function.